# How do I split this form into two columns, with the message field in the right hand column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My code below is trying to split the form into two columns. I want the message field in the right column and everything else in the left. Where am I going wrong? I'm also using code snippets to display the code for tweaking, if this is incorrect please let me know and I will use code blocks instead in the future.

```css
/* Flex container containing child elements */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* First flex child of container */

.col-1 {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Second flex child of container */

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

label {
  display: none;
}


/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Gray border */
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Rounded borders */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Make sure that padding and width stay in place */
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
  /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}


/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */

input [type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45A049;
}


/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Flexbox container for the form-->
  <div class="container">
    <form action="">
      <!--Column containing the name, email and subject boxes on the left-->
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name:">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email:">

        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject:">
      </div>

      <!--Column containing the message box on the right-->
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message:" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<div class="container">` inside the `<form>`, otherwise, the container only has one single child. You want `.col-1` and `.col-2` to be direct children of `.container`.

```html
<form action="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

btw, you might want to cleanup your CSS a bit, those `width` properties in `.col-1` and `.col-2` are not needed, and also, might want to add a `gap` style to `.container` for some breathing, like:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 10px;
}

/* So you dont probably don't need these two classes: */

.col-1 {
}

.col-2 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic errors in your code:

1.) `flex-direction: column;` needs to be erased to allow the default setting (`row`) to apply (i.e. the flex children should be *in a row*, not in a column).

2.) The remaining flexbox settings need to be applied to the `form` tag, not to `.container`.  The `form` tag is the *direct parent* of the two column elements which are your intended flex children. The `.container` div only contains the `form` tag as a direct child (i.e. *one element*), so flex has no effect there.

3.) Not necessary, but better looking: I also added `padding-right: 2%;` to the left column to create some distance between the form fields.

```css
/* Flex container containing child elements */

.container>form {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* First flex child of container */

.col-1 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}


/* Second flex child of container */

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

label {
  display: none;
}


/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Gray border */
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Rounded borders */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Make sure that padding and width stay in place */
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
  /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}


/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */

input [type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45A049;
}


/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Flexbox container for the form-->
  <div class="container">
    <form action="">
      <!--Column containing the name, email and subject boxes on the left-->
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name:">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email:">

        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject:">
      </div>

      <!--Column containing the message box on the right-->
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message:" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```